# Xamarin Android, can't set CG bridge to old mode (MONO_GC_PARAMS=bridge-implementation)

Tags: android, xamarin, garbage-collection

I have problems where my app crashes with the following error:

```
System.ArgumentException: Handle must be valid. Parameter name: instance
```

The error occurs when switching back and forth between 3 views a number of times. There is no consistency as to how many switches are needed but after a while it always leads to a crash. Multiple threads on both StackOverflow and other sites suggest trying to set the CG Bridge to using `Old` mode, however I can't seem to get this to work, changing the setting I mean. I have activated diagnostic level output when building the application but it always just prints:

```
MONO_GC_PARAMS = major=marksweep-conc,nursery-size=8m
```

I have created an environments.txt file and set Build Action to AndroidEnvironment, but it makes no difference. I have tried the file with both:

```
MONO_GC_PARAMS=bridge-implementation=old
```

and

```
MONO_GC_PARAMS=bridge-implementation=old,nursery-size=128‌​m,soft-heap-limit=51‌​2m,major=marksweep-c‌​onc
```

I see no difference in the (Re)Build output and the app still crashes at the exact same spot.

If no answer can be found for this specific problem, is this 'solution' still valid or can it no longer be done?

Comment: Your best bet here is to [File a Bug](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/wiki/Submitting-Bugs,-Feature-Requests,-and-Pull-Requests#bug-reports). Reverting to `old` and it **working** suggests a bug in the `tarjan` implementation. You can double check this is getting picked up by viewing a Diagnostic Build Output and ensuring your `AndroidEnvironment` file is being picked up.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47539289/xamarin-android-how-do-you-set-the-mono-gc-params-environment-variable/47541146#47541146 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47522381/xamarin-forms-mono-gc-params-bridge-implementation-old-how-to-tell-if-its-w/47523593#47523593

Answer (score 0):

In order to verify your `MONO_GC_PARAMS=bridge-implementation=` change did actually take effect:

1. Enable mono debug logs - `adb shell setprop debug.mono.log default,gc,mono_log_level=debug`
2. Observe mono adb logs - `adb logcat | grep -e "mono" -i`
3. Manually invoke a garbage collection inside your app - `System.GC.Collect()`
4. Look for logs that reference `GC_NEW_BRIDGE` or `GC_OLD_BRIDGE` depending on if `old`/`new` is set. You also have the `tarjen` option. `tarjen` has proven to cause many crashes for our team though.

The default option is `tarjen`. - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/internals/garbage-collection#gc-bridge-options

> The default setting is Tarjan. If you find a regression, you may find it necessary to set this option to Old. Also, you may choose to use the more stable Old option if Tarjan does not produce an improvement in performance.

For reference - Similar Xamarin Android GitHub Issue: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/6102